# In directory how can find files and apply md5sum of all files at same time?

Tags: linux, hashsum

How can find files then apply `md5sum` of all files?

Comment: What was the phrase you used for your web search so you didn't find the answer yourself? The `find` command is the obvious answer to finding files, and in the `man` page the `-exec` option is the obvious choice to execute something on the found files. I suggest to improve your searching skills, so you can answer questions like this by yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +
```